# Google Spreadsheet Trigger - User specific

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-sheets

I happen to notice this. I created a google spreadsheet and I shared it among three people.  I wrote a code for onEdit() trigger. I set the trigger(Resources->all your trigger-> create new trigger). If another user opens the google spreadsheet, the trigger I create is not available for him. He needs to set the same trigger again.

My question is: Is there anyway I can set trigger for all people for whom the spread sheet was shared? Is it possible? Or is creating a trigger user-specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an installable trigger that will be executed under your authority and will run for every user accessing the spreadsheet.
Installable triggers have less limitations than simple ones, read the documentation here : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Comment: Yes but onEdit should work too. I think hes just confused that the other user doesnt see it on his triggers list but that doesnt mean its not running